# asynchronous javascript prepare function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

To speed up my application I want to prepare some data before DOM is ready and then use this data when DOM is ready.

Here's how it might be:

```
var data = function prepareData(){
  ...
}();

$(document).ready(function() {

   // use data to build page

}
```

How to prepare the data for later use?
Thanks

Comment: prepare data means, what kind of data

Comment: What's wrong with your proposed solution?

Comment: How do you prepare data? where does the data come from? from the server? then it's better you do the preparation in the server itself.

Comment: @kobe - for example, analyze the cookie and make set

Comment: @megas depends upon where you are setting cookie , are you doing at server side

Comment: @RoccoC5 - the problem is that data not ready and because javascript is not multithread language then I can't wait until data is ready.

Comment: @Nivas - no server, just analyze local data

Comment: @megas. What do you mean by local data? Where does data come from?

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil" - so don't waste time trying to optimize things which most likely do not need any optimization and just make your code harder to read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You <s>need</s> *should use* parentheses around the function expression for clarity (and because in a similar situation where you're defining and calling a function but not using the return value, it would be a syntax error without them). Also, when you use a function expression, you want to not give it a name. So:

```
var data = (function(){
    ...
})();
```

or use a function *declaration* instead:

```
var data = processData();
function processData() {
    ...
}
```

(Why not use a name with a function expression? Because of bugs in various implementations, especially Internet Explorer prior to IE9, which [will create *two*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) completely unrelated functions.)

However, it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. When the browser reaches the `script` element, it hands off to the JavaScript interpreter and waits for it to finish before continuing building the DOM (because your script might use `document.write` to add to the HTML token stream). You can use the [`async` or `defer` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) to promise the browser you're not going to use `document.write`, on browsers that support them, but...

---

**Update**: Below you've said:

> because prepareData is long time function and I assumed that browser can execute this while it's building DOM tree. Unfortunately '$(document).ready' fires before prepareData is finished. The question is how to teach '$(document).ready' to wait for ready data

The only way the `ready` handler can possibly trigger while `processData` is running is if `processData` is using asynchronous ajax (or a couple of edge conditions around `alert`, `confirm`, and the like, but I assume you're not doing that). And if it were, you couldn't be returning the result as a return value from the function (though you could return an object that you continued to update as the result of ajax callbacks). Otherwise, it's impossible: JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded, the `ready` handler will queue waiting for the interpreter to finish its previous task (`processData`).

If `processData` isn't doing anything asynchronous, I suspect whatever the symptom is that you're seeing making you think the `ready` handler is firing *during* `processData` has a different cause.

But in the case of asynchronous stuff, three options:

1. If you're not in control of the ready handlers you want to hold up, you might look at jQuery's [`holdReady`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/) feature. Call `$.holdReady(true);` to hold up the event, and use `$.holdReady(false);` to stop holding it up.
2. It's simple enough to reschedule the `ready` handler. Here's how I'd do it (note that I've wrapped everything in a scoping function so these things aren't globals):

   ```
   (function() {
       var data = processData();

       $(onPageReady);

       function processData() {
       }

       function onPageReady() {
           if (!data.ready) {
               // Wait for it to be ready
               setTimeout(onPageReady, 0); // 0 = As soon as possible, you may want a
                                           // longer delay depending on what `processData`
                                           // is waiting for
               return;
           }
       }

   })();
   ```

   Note that I happily use `data` in the `onPageReady` function, because I *know* that it's there; that function will not run until `processData` has returned. But I'm assuming `processData` is returning an object that is slowly being filled in via ajax calls, so I've used a `ready` flag on the object that will get set when all the data is ready.
3. If you can change `processData`, there's a better solution: Have `processData` trigger the ready handler when it's done. Here's the code for when `processData` is done with what it needs to do:

   ```
   $(onPageReady);
   ```

   That works because if the DOM isn't ready yet, that just schedules the call. If the DOM is *already* ready, jQuery will call your function immediately. This prevents the messy looping above.

Comment: Well, the parentheses aren't required, the function is already on *expression context* (`LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression`), it won't cause a `SyntaxError`, but they are [encouraged](http://michaux.ca/articles/an-important-pair-of-parens). :)

Comment: @CMS: Ah, yes, you're right, they're only required when you're not using the result (and so you have to make it clear to the parser it's an expression, not a declaration).

Comment: because prepareData is long time function and I assumed that browser can execute this while it's building DOM tree. Unfortunately '$(document).ready' fires before prepareData is finished. The question is how to teach '$(document).ready' to wait for ready data